# Getting error: error no value given for one or more required parameters in vb.net for update sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net

These are the statement that having problems. Please do help me to solve this error which i believe because of my UPDATE statement

```
str = "UPDATE login SET Title=@Title,Author=@Author,Publisher=@Publisher,Series=@Series WHERE ISBN = @ISBN" 



            cmd = New OleDbCommand (str, Cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", author_name.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publisher", publish.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Series", series.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", Isbn_.Text)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: This usually happens when you are adding a parameter for which the value is null since a parameter will a null value won't actually be added to the command's parameter collection. Debug your code, and you should be able to check which parameters have and haven't been added to the collection, and find out which ones have a null value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that OleDb support parameters using the @ syntax. Try using a ? instead likle this:

```
str = "UPDATE login SET Title = ? ,Author = ?,Publisher = ?,Series = ?" & 
      "WHERE ISBN = ?" 

        cmd = New OleDbCommand (str, Cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", author_name.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publisher", publish.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Series", series.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", Isbn_.Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```